# Filter dataset for current month only

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a `dataset` with a column which contains dates (e.g. 09/17/20) as object. I want to `filter` all my rows based on the current month.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as  dt
from datetime import datetime    
df =  pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", dtype="unicode") 
now = datetime.now()
df['month_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month_start'], format = "%Y-%d-%m")
mask = df['month_start'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m") == datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m")
include = df[mask]
df.to_csv("dates.csv")
print(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m"))
```

My attempt doesn't `filter` the dates at all as I want rows with the current month only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the snippet.

I fetched all months from `dataframe` and stored it in a list and fetched all years and stored in another list which then i compared with current month and current year and then I accessed common values from both list and finally using index value I used `iloc` to locate the given rows

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df =  pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype="unicode") 
amon = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['month_start']).month.tolist()
ayear= pd.DatetimeIndex(df['month_start']).year.tolist()
bmon=[i for i,x in enumerate(amon) if((x==datetime.now().month))]
byear=[i for i,x in enumerate(ayear) if((x==datetime.now().year))]
common = [i for i in bmon if i in byear]
df=df.iloc[common]
```

```
Input
   month_start
0   08/17/2015
1   09/17/2015
2   09/17/2020
3   07/17/2020
4   06/17/2020

Output
  month_start
2    09/17/2020
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I have data from 2015. Your snippet only filters the month not the year

Comment: You want data based on current month as well as year? @Arron. Please edit your question to make it more understandable

Comment: Yes please for current month only